# Finding solutions to expression with initial estimates

Tags: equation-solving

I need to find solutions to Zo==50 with 4 variables w,s,h1 and h2. I have initial estimates for these variables that will come close to solving the equation, however I need to 'optimise' w,s,h1 and h2 to give me solution/s to Zo=50. Is there a way I can include these estimates in NSolve or something similar to compute s,w,h1 and h2 within a certain range?

```
In[142]:= Zo = Sqrt[Ll/Cl]

Out[142]= 94.2185 Sqrt[EllipticK[Sqrt[1 - w^2/(2 s + 
w)^2]]^2/(EllipticK[w/(2 s + w)]^2 (1 + (5.34 EllipticK[Sqrt[1 - w^2/(2 s + 
w)^2]]EllipticK[Csch[(\[Pi] (2 s + w))/(4 h1)] Sinh[(\[Pi] w)/(4 h1)]])/(
EllipticK[w/(2 s + w)] EllipticK[Sqrt[1 - Csch[(\[Pi] (2 s + w))/(4 h1)]^2 
Sinh[(\[Pi] w)/(4 h1)]^2]]) - (3.89 EllipticK[Sqrt[1 - w^2/(2 s + w)^2]] 
EllipticK[Csch[(\[Pi] (2 s + w))/(4 h2)] Sinh[(\[Pi] w)/(4 h2)]])/( 
EllipticK[w/(2 s + w)] EllipticK[Sqrt[1 - Csch[(\[Pi] (2 s + w))/(4 h2)]^2 
Sinh[(\[Pi] w)/(4 h2)]^2]])))]

In[179]:= Clear[s, h1, h2, w]

In[xx]:=NSolve[{Zo == 50, 0.1*10^-6 < w < 100*10^-6, 
0.1*10^-6 < s < 100*10^-6, 100*10^-6 < h1 < 1000*10^-6, 
100*10^-9 < h2 < 100*10^-9}, {w, s, h1, h2}]

Out[xx]:{}
```

I am unsure of NSolve syntax; i gave this a crack but it doesn't find any solutions

Thanks!

Comment: If you have initial sufficiently good estimates, then `FindRoot` should be the method of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)

```
Clear[Zo]

Zo = (94.2185 Sqrt[
       EllipticK[
          Sqrt[1 - w^2/(2 s + w)^2]]^2/(EllipticK[
            w/(2 s + 
               w)]^2 (1 + (5.34 EllipticK[
                Sqrt[1 - w^2/(2 s + w)^2]] EllipticK[
                Csch[(π (2 s + 
                    w))/(4 h1)] Sinh[(π w)/(4 h1)]])/(EllipticK[
                w/(2 s + w)] EllipticK[
                Sqrt[1 - 
                  Csch[(π (2 s + 
                    w))/(4 h1)]^2 Sinh[(π w)/(4 h1)]^2]]) - 
       (3.89 EllipticK[Sqrt[1 - w^2/(2 s + w)^2]] EllipticK[Csch[(π (2 s + 
                    w))/(4 h2)] Sinh[(π w)/(4 h2)]])/(EllipticK[
                w/(2 s + w)] EllipticK[
                Sqrt[1 - 
                  Csch[(π (2 s + 
                    w))/(4 h2)]^2 Sinh[(π w)/(4 h2)]^2]])))] /. 
     x_Real :> Rationalize[x]) // Simplify;

NMinimize[{Abs[Zo - 50], 10^-7 < w < 10^-4, 10^-7 < s < 10^-4, 
   10^-4 < h1 < 10^-3, 10^-8 < h2 < 10^-7}, {w, s, h1, h2}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50] // N

(* {3.41649*10^-21, {w -> 0.0000874514, s -> 0.0000441351, 
  h1 -> 0.000236364, h2 -> 7.19451*10^-8}} *)
```